# Why is it actually important for $p$ to be prime in the ring of $p$-adic numbers?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

In the proof that the set $Z_{[p]}$ of all $p$-adic numbers is a ring, it is not necessary for $p$ to be prime. Is it actually important for $p$ to be prime for the ring of $p$-adic numbers?

Comment: Also, which of the various existing definitions for the $p$-adic numbers do you use? One can give different answers to your question depending on what definition you are working with.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you for correcting me, I made an edit because I meant "necessary".

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Also, I like your remark that there are different definitions for the $p$-adic numbers. In my case, I am using the following:
 

$p$-adic number is a sequence of non-negative integers, $\hat{a} = <a_{1},a_{2},\ldots > = <a_{i}: i \in \mathbb{N}>$ 

$$a_{i} \in [0, p^{i} - 1]  \quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N} \quad \text{and}$$ 
$$a_{i+1}  \equiv a_{i}\ (\textrm{mod}\ p^{i}) \quad  \forall i \in \mathbb{N}  $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be any ring and $\mathfrak a\subset R$ be any ideal.
Then for all $n\in \Bbb N$, $\mathfrak a^n$ is also an ideal, hence we have quotient rings $R/\mathfrak a^n$, and of course we have natural  homomorphisms $R/\mathfrak a^n\to\ R/\mathfrak a^m$ whenever $m>n$. From this, we arrive at the projective limit
$$ \lim_\leftarrow R/\mathfrak a^n.$$
This does not require $\mathfrak a$ to be prime.

Comment: However, $\mathfrak a$ must be prime if we want an integral domain. This is why the prime-adic rings are set aside as their own thing.

Answer (score 1):

For $a=\prod_{p|a} p^{e(p)}$ non-prime we have $$\varprojlim \Bbb{Z}/(a^n)=\varprojlim \Bbb{Z}/(\prod_{p|a}p^{e(p)n})\cong \varprojlim \prod_{p|a}\Bbb{Z}/(p^{e(p)n})$$ $$\cong \prod_{p|a}\varprojlim \Bbb{Z}/(p^{e(p)n})=\prod_{p| a} \Bbb{Z}_p$$
Which is the completion of $\Bbb{Z}$ for the norm $$\| \frac{c}{d} \prod_{p| a} p^{r(p)}\|_a = 2^{-\min_p r(p)}, \qquad \gcd(a,cd)=1$$
This norm is not an absolute value when $a$ has more than one prime divisor.

The completion of $\Bbb{Q},\|.\|_a$ is isomorphic to $\prod_{p|a} \Bbb{Q}_p$.